# Creating A Log Of Files In A Folder and update into table

Tags: database, logging

Can anyone help me to build a table that lists all files in a specified folder, so whenever a file is copied to that folder the table should update and make a log of files?

I need the list to retain the names, even if the file is moved from that folder or deleted. Later the data would be deleted by a scheduler.

Also I need the table to record the time exactly when the file was copied into that folder and not the modification or creation time.

I am using windows 7; how can I build a system with my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Just turn on [Windows file auditing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Lot58yAEKM), for that folder, the youtube video takes you through the process.

Microsoft provide information on their [techNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692659.aspx) site as to how you can use the [LogParser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910447) tool to extract Security events from the Event Log DB.

Note: Admin questions should really be posted to the **[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/about)** site.

Comment: thanks for your answer and i checked the video. but how do i get the list of files with time of copy and write them to a log file? and just another query, what is admin questions?

Comment: This forum is for programming questions, system administration (Admin)  questions should be posted to one of the other stack exchange sites.